# Position Textarea on the click of series data

Tags: java, gwt, highcharts

is there anyway to show textarea (for inserting custom text) instead of tooltips on clicking of the data points on the chart serie in gwt highcharts, or it can be only shown the tooltips on the chart, not outside the chart?

```
chart.setSeriesPlotOptions(new SeriesPlotOptions().setPointClickEventHandler(new PointClickEventHandler() {


                @Override
                public boolean onClick(final PointClickEvent pointClickEvent) {
                    Point[] points = chart.getSelectedPoints();
                    int posX = pointClickEvent.getScreenX();
                    int posY = pointClickEvent.getScreenY();
                    return true;
                }

            }));
```

i can't understand how to set position for the textarea, any suggestions?

```
EDIT: 
Anyone already used annotations or similar with Java in highcharts gwt?
```

Comment: See the [annotations plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/17/Annotations)

Comment: thank you, is it also possible to save inserted annotations?

Comment: In the chart object you have annotations array, which can be save anywahere. Then when you load any chart, get data from database or somewhere where you save this array.

Comment: is there some samples available?

Comment: can you tell me please, is this plugin works only for the one/first chart on the site? i have many charts on the site, but can set annotations only on the first chart.

Comment: Works for each of them, you need to have an annotation array in the chart cofnigruation.

Comment: did you mean it with js? create a js function in java for getting annotation array? but how could it be done without js, only java? i can't get any annotation calls from my chart object.

Comment: Im not familiar with java, so I'm talking about javascript.